# Gather data tidy in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

**What the case is:**

So I got a "results sample" in excel format that needs filtering and reshaping to look nice. It is a result that will be not identical all the time but it follows similar rules. I have to filter it further and make it a little more tidy. I have figured out the filtering part, but I am not sure how to sort the remaining data, in a tidy way.

**What the situation is:**

There are six columns involved.

**Notice:** Real deal is not THAT simple, but what I need can be demonstrated using such a simple example and then I can manage more complex stuff myself I suppose.

For our example we use columns from B to G
The data are set as pairs of a "title" and a value.
For instance, if you look the first example picture I provide, The first detais the pair B3 and C3.

As you can see, looking at the same picture, D3 and E3 is an empty pair.
Same goes for D4 - E4 and F4 - G4 and so on until a last one at B11 - C11. 
Starting data example:

[[image: Scattered data]]

**What I want to achieve:**

I would like, using Visual Basic for Applications, to sort the data, starting from let's say for our example B3 (see second picture) and fill three SETS of two columns, (BC, DE, FG) if there are no data inside those cells.

Notice: If a cell like D3 is null then SURELY E3 will be null too so there can be just only one check. I mean we can check either value columns or title columns.

Notice2: The B,D,F or C,E,G columns DON'T have to be sorted. I just want all the not-null values of B,D,F and their respective values from C,E,G gathered together neat so printing will not need 30 pages but just a few (too many spaces between is causing it and I try to automate the cleanup)

[image: Sorted data]

Comment: You're more likely to receive assistance if you can show what code you've already tried. Any chance you could edit your question and add your coding attempt?

Comment: I have not started anything yet, I am on the design part of this part.
This simple example solved can help me out figure what I have to do.
It is pretty simple and it is exactly how things should work.
Simple things though are almost never easy to be done.

Comment: Ah ok. You might get lucky with a response but I doubt it. Your best bet would be to post again once you have some even rudimentary code to show. You've probably already seen that this site helps correct existing code rather than write code from scratch. Having said that, if your question shows a lot of coding effort, then many will do the same in return and sometimes produce a substantial solution.

Comment: You are probably right, I don't ask for someone to do my job, I will try some things alone and if I get no luck I will edit the post including my thoughts on the approach and the code. Your suggestion is not bad at all, this question might actually look like lazy-guy-asking-for-something. The fact is that I am not too experienced with VBA framework, I still have a good background on VB .Net though. I actually work on it at the moment, if I get no answers I will probably follow your suggestions. In any case thank you for caring. :)

Comment: Well a good approach I think of, is cut the data, put them into two arrays, then place them back nice and smooth. The rest is just writing the algorithm down.
Another approach could be not using arrays but checking every time from start of the region all cells until we reach an empty then paste the data in that and the next to it cell. I am not sure what approach to use yet, but it seems to me that arrays is the winner, because storing the data to the array, can be useful for further extensive editing of the data by the algorithm.

Comment: Added a clarification about sorting as "Notice2:".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we got all variables set and initialized properly, in this example:

```
Sheets("sheetname").Select ' because stupid things can happen...
For i = 3 To 13
    Let newrangeT = "B" & i '
    Let newrangeV = "C" & i '            
    If Sheets("sheetname").Range(newrangeV) <> "" Then
        values(Position) = Sheets("sheetname").Range(newrangeV)
        titles(Position) = Sheets("sheetname").Range(newrangeT)
        Position = Position + 1 
     Else
        ' Don't do anything if the fields are null
     End If
Next i

Sheets("sheetname").Range("B1:G13").Clear
```

' We then get each data from the arrays with a For loop.
  ' We set a columnset variable to 1.
  ' We set a currentrow variable to 3.
  ' If columnset is 1 data will enter in B and C and columnset = columnset +1
  ' Then if columnset is 2 we set data to DE and columnset = columnset +1
  ' But if columnset is  2we set data to FG and columnset = 1 and currentrow = currentrow +1
  ' Iterating the arrays will result in a neat setting of the data, but it will add zeros for all the nulls. Thus we need an If statement that will exclude that values checking the TITLE array (that should contain a title instead). if the value is not 0 then... we run what I describe, otherwise we do nothing.

Putting the data in the array is half of the trick.

Then we clear the area.

We set two string variables to declare ranges (actually cell reference) for every cell iterated in the loop. Here I demonstrated only for column set B,C
but we have to do the same for the rest of the columns.
The If statement here checks for null. You might have different needs, so changing the if statement changes the filtering. Here I check if the cells are not null. If the cells of column C contain data, put those data in values array and the respective B data on titles array but where? Position starts as 1 and we then iterate it +1 each time it adds something.

You can set data from an array using this command:

```
' current_row is set to the first row of the spreadsheet we wanna fill.
Sheets("sheetname").Select ' because stupid things can happen...
newrangeV = "C" & current_row
Sheets("sheetname").Range(newrangeV) = values(j)
```

The rest is just putting things together.

In any case, I wanna thank both of the people involved in this question, because I might didn't got the solution, but I got an idea of how to do other stuff, like accidentally learning something new. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to start with.  The first double loop populates a VBA Collection with Range variables that refer to the Cells that contain the titles. 
 The associated values are obtained by using an offset. The middle double loop performs a  bubble sort on the latter (highly inefficient - you might want to replace it with something else).  The next if statement creates a 2nd sheet if it doesn't exist on which to write out the results (last loop).

```
Option Explicit


Sub GatherData()
  Dim lastRow As Integer, lastCol As Integer
  Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
  Dim vals As Collection
  Set vals = New Collection

  With Sheets(1)
    lastCol = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
    lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
    For c = 1 To lastCol Step 2
      For r = 1 To lastRow
        If (Trim(Cells(r, c).Value) <> "") Then
          vals.Add .Cells(r, c)
        End If
      Next
    Next
  End With

  ' Bubble Sort
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  Dim vTemp As Range
  For i = 1 To vals.Count - 1
    For j = i + 1 To vals.Count
      If vals(i).Value > vals(j).Value Then
        Set vTemp = vals(j)
        vals.Remove j
        vals.Add vTemp, vTemp, i
      End If
    Next j
  Next i

  Dim sht2 As Worksheet
  If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count = 1 Then
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1))
  Else
    Set sht2 = Worksheets(2)
  End If

  With sht2
    r = 3
    c = 2
    For i = 1 To vals.Count
      .Cells(r, c).Value = vals(i).Value
      .Cells(r, c + 1).Value = vals(i).Offset(, 1).Value
      c = c + 2
      If c = 8 Then
        r = r + 1
        c = 2
      End If
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take a look at your code and see if I can use something that fits the needs. What I am about to use is arrays for sure, so even looking at how things work will be pretty helpful. Instead of a bubble sort I believe I can pretty much use if statements that check if a cell is null and actually filter out null entries. That's what I came up with the last 24 hours as a thought. Your code though can be useful, since it  utilizes offsets, thus I believe I can simplify my code using that feature.

Comment: The alternate solution provided needlessly stores the value into the in-memory dictionary when it's already on the page - in effect duplicating the value information.   My solution simply stores a reference to the pair on the page (ie stores a Range variable) and does the sort on that - which you have to do anyway.    I would swap out the sort with a heap sort (most efficient) - there's an example on-line using vba (see this [page](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/vbasic/1.htm)).

Comment: Neither of the sorting methods was needed, I think the question was clear but in any case I added a notice on that fact. 
What I asked for, was just gathering together the data, the way I had shown on the pictures. The pictures show no sorting, just a gathering of data from all around the spreadsheet.
I am just not sure yet which of the two answers will be the most helpful. I am actually at the middle of what I am doing, it is a different approach.

Comment: I used two cells as anchors (adding distinct data inside them) so using a search later I can offset from them to enter lines, according to the gathered data. Data are stored into arrays, thus I can really manipulate them accordingly. No sorting needed anyway.
When the method ends, the arrays are destroyed (not that anyone would have a RAM problem here whatsoever) and things are kept neat and clear.

Both of you helped me out and even inspired me for potential future enhancements. I thank you both. According to the potential of your replies, I will accept one answer as most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using the Dictionary object.  I use early binding which requires setting a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  If you are going to be distributing this, you might want to convert this to late-binding.

We assume that your data is properly formed as you show it above.  In other words, all the titles are in even numbered columns; and the results are in the adjacent cell.

We create the dictionary using the Title as the `Key`, and the adjacent cell value for the Dictionary item.

- We collect the information
- Transfer the Keys to a VBA array and sort alphabetically
- create a "Results Array" and populate it in order
- write the results to a worksheet.

I will leave formatting and header generation to you.
By the way, there is a constant in the code for the number of Title/Value pair columns.  I have set it to `3`, but you can vary that.

Enjoy

---

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'If you want the sorting to be case INsensitive
'set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub TidyData()
    'Assume Titles are in even numbered columns
    'Assume want ColPairs pairs of columns for output
    'Use dictionary with Title as key, and Value as the item
  Dim dctTidy As Dictionary
  Dim arrKeys As Variant
  Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
  Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
  Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
  Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, L As Long
  Dim V As Variant

  'in Results
  Const ColPairs As Long = 3

'Set Source and results worksheet and range
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 2)

'Read source data into variant array
With wsSrc.Cells
    LastRow = .Find(what:="*", after:=.Item(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastCol = .Find(what:="*", after:=.Item(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
End With

'Collect the data into a dictionary
Set dctTidy = New Dictionary
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    For J = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 2) Step 2
        If vSrc(I, J) <> "" Then _
            dctTidy.Add Key:=vSrc(I, J), Item:=vSrc(I, J + 1)
    Next J
Next I

'For this purpose, we can do a simple sort on the dictionary keys,
' and then create our results array in the sorted order.

arrKeys = dctTidy.Keys
Quick_Sort arrKeys, LBound(arrKeys), UBound(arrKeys)

'Create results array
ReDim vRes(1 To WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(dctTidy.Count / ColPairs, 0), 1 To ColPairs * 2)
I = 0
J = 0

For Each V In arrKeys
    K = Int(I / ColPairs) + 1
    L = (J Mod ColPairs) * 2 + 1
    vRes(K, L) = V
    vRes(K, L + 1) = dctTidy(V)
    I = I + 1
    J = J + 1
Next V

'write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .Worksheet.Cells.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

End Sub

Sub Quick_Sort(ByRef SortArray As Variant, ByVal first As Long, ByVal last As Long)
Dim Low As Long, High As Long
Dim Temp As Variant, List_Separator As Variant
Low = first
High = last
List_Separator = SortArray((first + last) / 2)
Do
    Do While (SortArray(Low) < List_Separator)
        Low = Low + 1
    Loop
    Do While (SortArray(High) > List_Separator)
        High = High - 1
    Loop
    If (Low <= High) Then
        Temp = SortArray(Low)
        SortArray(Low) = SortArray(High)
        SortArray(High) = Temp
        Low = Low + 1
        High = High - 1
    End If
Loop While (Low <= High)
If (first < High) Then Quick_Sort SortArray, first, High
If (Low < last) Then Quick_Sort SortArray, Low, last
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Well, that's a good idea indeed. One question though. Imagine a big spreadsheet that always follows the same form. Thus I can automate stuff to be done on it. So, I was thinking a complex if statement that will take care of populating an array using a For loop to iterate through the lines. 
Like for i = 1 to 14, if Bi NOT NULL then get its value and Ci value and put them into respective arrays.
Next thing I do is delete the contents from the spreadsheet...
and then I just get the contents of the arrays and put them back in the spreadsheet. No sorting involved. Does it look cool?

Comment: P.S. The spreadsheet is big but will take no more than a few seconds at MOST to do the whole stuff I suppose. I am not talking here about megabytes of data, but it's not of course as simple as the example. So how does my approach sound to you?

Comment: @GeorgeEco sounds more complicated to me for what you want to do. Why don't you try it and compare the two methods? Dictionary lookups are super fast, and you still have to sort your arrays anyway.

Comment: Will do and come back to share my thoughts. Dictionary was a really good idea though, it is a matter of time to accept this answer to be honest, since it gave me a really good approach I didn't thought myself (gee how could I forget the utility of dictionaries) so I'll be back soon as long as I will finish with what I do. Gimme some time though, cause it is a part of a lot more stuff to be done.

Comment: I thought about it on the other hand and I am not sure if a Dictionary would be helpful here. There is not a lot of data manipulation involved, just a set on RAM and them back to the spreadsheet using a button click. But still, the answer is well documented and showed  me how some neat things are done.

Comment: @GeorgeEco Different strokes, for sure.  And since I posted, you indicated no need for sorting the results (in which case I might use a Collection object instead).  But still, I find the dictionary object to be useful in collecting randomly distributed data of uncertain size, and then spitting it back (in either a sorted or unsorted fashion) into an array properly sized for the results.  But, for sure, you can also do this in arrays, or even on the worksheet (although that would incur a large speed penalty).